# How to close a com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse object properly

Tags: java, httpresponse

I am trying to close a `com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse` object, but I get the Eclipse error

> Unhandled exception type IOException

on the line `response.disconnect();`

**Here's a code example:**

```
HttpRequest request = null;
HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    request = this.buildJsonApiRequest(apiUrl);
    response = this.execute(request);
    return response.parseAs(MyClass.class);
} catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new DaoException(e);
} finally {
    if (response != null) { 
        response.disconnect();
    }
}
```

The code works without the `finally` block, but I am concerned about many response objects being opened and not closed. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I would really like to know if `parseAs()` API method closes the stream... I cannot seem to find any info on the implementation of this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the disconnect call within a `try-catch block` because according to Google API documentation that method could throw an IOException:

```
public void disconnect() throws IOException
```

**Follow this link to learn more about it:**

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponse#disconnect()

Comment: Note that the API states "disconnect() does not have to be called if the response stream is properly closed.". However, the API isn't too clear about how `parseAs(Class)` handles the response stream.

Comment: Does that mean I have to nest another try catch in the finally just to close a (possibly) open connection? Seems inefficient...

Comment: Agree, but the `disconnect method` signature states that.

Comment: As @Izruo said, the API isn't too clear about how parseAs(Class) handles the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to Eleazar Enrique answer that the disconnect needs to be within a try block. This is an example of how to possibly write it more elegantly and make it reusable.

You could create a handler class that implements autoCloseable then use try-with-resource

```
public class HttpResponseHandler implements AutoCloseable {
    private HttpResponse response;
    public HttpResponseHandler(HttpResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}

public <T> T parseAs(Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    return response.parseAs(clazz);
}

@Override
public void close() {
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            response.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

then in your code it would be something like this

```
HttpRequest request = this.buildJsonApiRequest(apiUrl);

try (HttpResponseHandler handler = new HttpResponseHandler(this.execute(request)) {
    return handler.parseAs(MyClass.class);
} catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new DaoException(e);
}
```

The AutoCloseable will close the connection for you, so you wouldn't have to handle it in the finally block.